# How to deal with multitype data sources in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, data, dxf

Today I was trying to import a DXF to Qgis, the result is that qgis displays everything LINES and POINTS but it only displays options for the POINT objects.
When I try to export to a shapefile, it throws an error (Can't export LINES).
When I try to export to geojson, that's ok, it exports everything.

What I want is to separate POINTS from LINES so I can work with them. Is there any workaround or suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The v.in.ogr.dxf module of GRASS (also available in QGIS trough the QGIS/GRASS plugin) works better (in same cases) than the OGR driver (that QGIS uses to handle DXFs). Once imported it in a GRASS location/mapset you can easy export by just clicking "save as...".

Answer (score 3):

The dxf is an ascii file.
You probably could copy your orig dxf 2 times and then just delete the line section from one,
 and the point section from the other.
should be group code 10.

[dxf group codes](http://www.afralisp.net/reference/dxf-group-codes.php)